# Sorting multiple lists like another list

Tags: python-3.x

This one is a bit tricky. I have a list: `list_a=[5.,4.,2.,6.]` and i want to order this list by ascending but also do the same ordering to another list: `list_b=[left,up,right,down]`. The output should be:

```
list_a=[2.,4.,5.,6.]
list_b=[right,up,left,down]
```

In reality the lists are huge and variable but have the same len (list_a is though always number and a dot). I want to copy the ordering of the list_a to list_b.

Thanks!

Comment: @Therd1979 Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share with us your code that shows us how did you try to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` and `sorted` for this,

```
sorted_list_b = [x for _,x in sorted(zip(list_a,list_b))]
print(sorted(list_a))
print(sorted_list_b)
```